# Enterprise library 6 logging to database and email not working on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library, iis-8.5

I have configured email and database logging using Enterprise Library 6, on a .NET 4.5 MVC application.

It all works well when run in Visual Studio. However, when deployed to the server it does not work, nothing gets logged.

Here is the configuration set up on the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>

  <!--logging start-->
  <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true"
    defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Database Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.FormattedDatabaseTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.Configuration.FormattedDatabaseTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database"
        databaseInstanceName="procLoggingConnection" writeLogStoredProcName="WriteLog"
        addCategoryStoredProcName="AddCategory" formatter="Text Formatter"
        traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" />
      <add name="Email Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        toAddress="test@test.com" fromAddress="test@test.com"
        subjectLineStarter="Test subject: " subjectLineEnder=" "
        smtpServer="mailserver" formatter="Text Formatter" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
        template="Timestamp: {timestamp} Message: {message} Category: {category} Priority: {priority} EventId: {eventid} Severity: {severity} Title:{title} Machine: {machine} Application Domain: {appDomain} Process Id: {processId} Process Name: {processName} Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId} Thread Name: {threadName} Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value} )}"
        name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
          <add name="Email Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings" />
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="procLoggingConnection" />
  <!--logging end-->

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="procLoggingConnection" connectionString="my connection string here"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have this code in the global.asax file:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        IConfigurationSource configurationSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
        LogWriterFactory logWriterFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configurationSource);
        DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory());
        Logger.SetLogWriter(logWriterFactory.Create(), false);
    }
```

When writing a log, I am doing it like this:

```
var logEntry = new LogEntry
    {
        Title = "test log entry",
        Message = fullExceptionInfo,
        Severity = System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error,
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now
    };

    Logger.Write(logEntry);
```

I would like to this all to work on the server.

Comment: Try running a debugger on the server and see if it's throwing an error when it goes to write the error. It may be a file permission issue.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth I have ran the remote debugger on the server. The Logger.Write call is not throwing an error.

Comment: While debugging, make sure the properties of the logger are correct and it seems setup properly.